# Select count returns null instead of 0 inside inner join

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which I am using to get a list of user names from table `users` that haven't sent a request to or received a request from a user with id 'xXXXxXXxxx' in table `friends`:

```
SELECT u.user, f1.c1, f2.c2
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT uid, fid, COUNT(*) AS c1
    FROM friends f
    WHERE f.fid = 'xXXXxXXxxx'
) AS f1
ON f1.uid = u.uid
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT uid, fid, count(*) AS c2
    FROM friends f
    WHERE f.uid = 'xXXXxXXxxx'
) AS f2
ON f2.fid = u.uid;
```

The output:

```
+------------+------+------+
| user       | c1   | c2   |
+------------+------+------+
| User1      | NULL | NULL |
| User2      | NULL | 1    |
| User3      | NULL | NULL |
| User4      | 1    | NULL |
| User5      | NULL | NULL |
+------------+------+------+
```

Why am I getting NULL value for counts instead of 0? and is there a better way to run this query?

Comment: Did you try use `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @user yes it didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your result is correct except 0 then you can use the `IFNULL()` function for get 0 like `IFNULL(f1.c1,0)`;

```
SELECT u.user,IFNULL(f1.c1,0), IFNULL(f2.c2,0)
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT uid, fid, COUNT(*) AS c1
    FROM friends f
    WHERE f.fid = 'xXXXxXXxxx'
 ) AS f1
ON f1.uid = u.uid
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT uid, fid, count(*) AS c2
    FROM friends f
    WHERE f.uid = 'xXXXxXXxxx'
) AS f2
ON f2.fid = u.uid;
```

Also use GROUP BY to get one row of user count by user

> LEFT JOIN: The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table
>   (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The
>   result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.

[image]

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

now if you want to want to get 0 then you should use `IFNULL()` funciton

Comment: My question is why is it null, if you run `select count(*) from users where 1=0` for example it returns 0

Comment: In your query you use left join and if you use left join, you get all row from left table rather its column match from  right table column or not. if there is no match any column of right table its return `NULL`. not `0`.

Comment: @Vipin_jain could you remove `GROUP BY` suggestion in your answer because it doesn't have any impact

Comment: Ok @razzak. But here i used group by because same user have multiple row so its return multiple rows with count, if you use group by then its return only one row with count

Comment: Thankx, in the users table the uid column is unique so this won't make a difference really

Answer (score 1):

Or simply do

```
SELECT user, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friends f WHERE f.uid=u.uid AND f.fid = 'xXXXxXXxxx') f1,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friends f WHERE f.fid=u.uid AND f.uid = 'xXXXxXXxxx') f2
FROM users u
```

**Edit**, to comply with your comment below you could do

```
SELECT * FROM 
       ( SELECT user, 
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friends f WHERE f.uid=u.uid AND f.fid = 'xXXXxXXxxx') f1,
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friends f WHERE f.fid=u.uid AND f.uid = 'xXXXxXXxxx') f2
         FROM users u
       ) uu 
WHERE f1 = 0 AND f2 = 0
```

Alternatively, a simpler query, listing only names of users that comply with your condition would be

```
SELECT user FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM friends f WHERE u.uid IN (f.uid,f.fid) 
                                     AND 'xXXXxXXxxx' IN (f.uid,f.fid) )
```

Comment: if i want to add a where close at the end of the query how do i reference f1 and f2? lets say for example `where f1 = 0 and f2 = 0`

Comment: Thanks, +1 for adding f1 and f2 references but this query is not much better that the one i'm using.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.uid, 
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friends f WHERE f.uid=u.uid AND f.fid = 'xXXXxXXxxx') c1,
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friends f WHERE f.uid=u.uid AND f.uid = 'xXXXxXXxxx') c2
         FROM users u

WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friends f WHERE f.uid=u.uid AND f.fid = 'xXXXxXXxxx')  = 0
OR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friends f WHERE f.uid=u.uid AND f.uid = 'xXXXxXXxxx') = 0
```